# Same key for both GCM and Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-messaging

I am bit confused about the API keys required for Google Maps.I have a project which already has a key registered for GCM Notifications. Now I also want to include Google Maps v2 in my application. So is it necessary that I create a new Android Key as specified in the Google Developers Site documentation and provide the SHA1 Key or can I use the same API Key as I am already using.
If it has to be same do I need to do something additional rather than just switching On the Google Maps service.
Else how can I specify two different keys in my android manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maps has Android key, whereas GCM needs Server key so you will need to register for android key to integrate maps within your application.